# Polylin Not Removing in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I try to removing polylines. But polyline remove is not work. 
So I checked polyline getPoints(). This is result.
It's result after using polyline remove().

```
03-24 16:36:13.520 21334-21334/kr.co.wdream D/Poly: polyline : [lat/lng: (37.4851709,126.8986303)]
03-24 16:36:13.520 21334-21334/kr.co.wdream D/Poly: polyline2 : [lat/lng: (37.4851709,126.8986303)]
```

Is this normal? Why doesn't erase location(Point)?
I think, this is cause about erasing polyline.
How can i do..? help me please.

Oh , I'm so sorry.
First, I tried to using in buttonClickListener. but didn't active.
Second, tried to using onLocationChange. Just for test.

```
 static PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED);
    static Polyline polyline;

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
Location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            if (latitude != 0 && prev_latitude == 0) {
                start_position = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Location).title("시작 위치"));
            }
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Location, 17));

            polyline = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions.add(Location));

            Log.d("Poly", "polyline : " + polyline.getPoints());
            polyline.remove();
            Log.d("Poly", "polyline2 : " + polyline.getPoints());
}
```

///////-----------------------------//////

```
case R.id.btn_location:
                if(mStatus == IDLE || mStatus==START) {
                    if(polyline!=null) {
                        map.clear();
                        polyline.remove();
                    }
```

Comment: provide some code. where you are trying to remove the polylines

Comment: Oh , I'm so sorry.

Comment: Do you still see the polyline on the map after `polyline.remove();`?

Comment: is your map is clearing or not? make sure if condition is true when you click on this button

Comment: @antonio Yes. polyline is redrawing after start. So confuse which one is drawing line.

Comment: @MustanserIqbal Idon't understrand what you say. There is map.clear().